# How to set a toolbar in a List Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to change the app I have created so far, in order to implement a `ListView`. I followed [this example](http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90) and [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/). The examples alone work, but not together with the changes I had to make to my so-far existing app.

I have a `avticity_main.xml` defined as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_grid"

        android:useDefaultMargins="true"
        android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"

        android:columnCount="4"
        >

        <TextView
            android:text="MainTitle"
            android:textSize="32dip"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
        </ListView>                            
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and I have the following code for my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    static final String[] MOBILE_OS =
        new String[] { "Android", "iOS", "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));
```

The code compiles fine, but no list is shown.

Comment: `Any ideas?` Yes: don't use ListActivity. Use ActionBarActivity (or AppCompatActivity). Simply put your ListView in a normal layout.

Comment: Can you then please provide a WORKING example on how to implement a ListView then? Maybe I looked at the wrong example! I am trying to display several items dynamically in rows. I have trying this for almost 4 hours now...

Comment: Yes, you looked at the wrong example. Or... well, you're mixing some old technology (ListActivity/ListFragment) with some new one (the ActionBars). What a ListActivity does is only to avoid the `findViewById()` part in the `onCreate()` method. But you're very limited (i.e.: only 1 ListView per Activity)

Comment: Yes probably! It is really hard to see if an example is 'good' or 'not so good'. Now, the code compiles but crashes...

Comment: Did you forget the `findViewById()` part? or did you leave the "standard" id (`"@android:id/list"`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) is a "convenience" class to implement a simple `ListView`. And that's pretty much all you can do. So, there's no `setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)` there.

To achieve what you want, use [`AppCompatActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) or default [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

[This link](http://androidessence.com/how-to-replace-the-android-actionbar-with-toolbar/) provides a nice tutorial on how to use the new `ToolBar` instead of the old `ActionBar`.

You want something like this:

[image: Layout sample]

This layout example could be used:

**P.S.:** `"@color/primary"` could be any color like `#FF009688`.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:elevation="4dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/lv"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And on the Java side:

**YourActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ListView lv;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        // Populate the ListView here...

    }

}
```

---

**EDIT:** [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462112/listview-updated-from-edittext/30462677#30462677) of mine can show you how to create a Custom Adapter to display the data you want on the `ListView`.

**Second edit:** Use this layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_grid"

        android:useDefaultMargins="true"
        android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"

        android:columnCount="4"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:text="MainTitle"
            android:textSize="32dip"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**What did I do?**

Your `LinearLayout` was lacking the `orientation` parameter on the XML, and your `TextView` had a `android:layout_height` set to `match_parent`, so it was filling the entire layout. I've changed it to `wrap_content` and you're good to go.

Comment: But how to include a ListView in that activity and a toolbar?

Comment: I want something like you have posted, but actually each row consisting of multiple items: a name, a number, a  number again, a small clickable icon...

Comment: Maybe then I again need something completly different?

Comment: I have my code in principle like your example. Please see my activity xml above...

Comment: You'll have to create a Custom Adapter for your `ListView` to display such a thing. Check the linked answer on how to do that, and don't use ListViewActivity ;)

Comment: I am using an adapter, as shown in this example: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Comment: So what problem are you still having?

Comment: So far, things are good again (well, like they have been 4 hours ago). What is not working right now is that the ListView is empty! The text "MainTitle" is shown, but nothing else. This is the problem I have...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95858/discussion-between-mauker-and-alex).

Answer (score 4):

setSupportActionBar(toolbar) is not available in ListActivity. You can use AppCompatActivity instead and just get a reference to the listview:
 ListView list = findViewById(R.id.list); and use list.setAdapter(adapter) instead of setListAdapter(adapter);

Comment: I used AppCompatActivity  before! But how to have a ListView then?

Comment: ListView list = findViewById(R.id.list); and use list.setAdapter(adapter) instead of setListAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Hmm, code compiles and does not crash, but I do not see a list of items. Maybe a issue with the layout xml file?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in ListActivity.

If you want to access getSupportActionBar(), you need to extent your class by AppCompatActivity.

My Suggestion : Don`t use ListActivty is you want to use ToolBar. Create an Activity and then only have ListView within that Activity. It'll work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new `AppCompatDelegate` component provided by the Support Library to easily add a Toolbar to your ListActivity.

Follow this link,

[How to add Toolbar to an Activity which doesn't extend AppCompatActivity](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/)

Answer (score 0):

***OR***

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);

// Set an OnMenuItemClickListener to handle menu item clicks
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle the menu item
        return true;
    }
});

// Inflate a menu to be displayed in the toolbar
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.your_toolbar_menu);
```

}`