# onlistitemclick in AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, listview, appcompatactivity

I followed steps mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33857770) to set a toolbar for a listview [listview image][1].

Now the list items are not clickable. When using ListActivity list items were clickable, when clicking on any item it will open another activity with item title and its content.

```
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Note note = posts.get(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditNoteActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("noteId", note.getId());
    intent.putExtra("noteTitle", note.getTitle());
    intent.putExtra("noteContent", note.getContent());
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/titkg.png

Comment: Have a look at my answer !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         Note note = posts.get(position);
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditNoteActivity.class);
         intent.putExtra("noteId", note.getId());
         intent.putExtra("noteTitle", note.getTitle());
         intent.putExtra("noteContent", note.getContent());
         startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not working, says cannot resolve symbol 'listview' and 3 more errors

Comment: @Rashid Change listView to the name of the listView that you are using in your app

Comment: 'code'public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private List<Note> posts;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
'code'

Comment: I did that, but the same error cannot resolve symbol 'setOnItemClickListener'

Comment: Really? lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                 Note note = posts.get(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditNoteActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("noteId", note.getId());
    intent.putExtra("noteTitle", note.getTitle());
    intent.putExtra("noteContent", note.getContent());
    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });  doesn't work, just paste it !!

Comment: Yes, got same error. Change the code position to just below the onCreate method and got a new error I'm working on. Sorry I'm a newbee.

Comment: If it is a problem simply post your full code after the changes in the question

Comment: Other errors are fixed. A new error at this line  Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditNoteActivity.class);    it says cannot resolve constructor intent...

Comment: @Rashid Change this to MainActivity.this

Comment: Thanks a lot,Varun. When I moved the code to Oncreate method section it all worked, Why?

Comment: @Rashid It should be in onCreate where was it earlier ?

Comment: You mean outside the functions ? It should be in onCreate or onResume , I think you declared it in the class outside the methods.