# How to change data of the current fragment in TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, fragment, android-tablayout

How is it possible to change dynamically the content of the current `fragment` in `TabLayout`. For example, if there is a list on the current fragment, and the list is changed, how to update the fragment layout?

Here is the default generated code (selected from `New`-> `Activity`->`Tabbed Activity`)

```
 public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        int areaID = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, areaID));
        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Mauker I have an ArrayList and ListView and when the ArrayList is changed I want to display that changed ArrayList on the current fragment

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not a `Fragment` problem per say. Since you're using a `ListView`, you could either use a predefined adapter, or create your own custom adapter. Check [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462112/listview-updated-from-edittext/30462677#30462677) on how to create a custom one.

But long story short you'll need to:

- Either use an [`ArrayAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) (As seem on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079400/arrayadapter-in-android-to-create-simple-listview)), or create your own, as stated above on my answer.
- Every time you modify your adapter/dataset, call the method `myAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged();`