# LinearLayout using half screen

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I have a `ScrollView` and a vertical `LinearLayout` inside that. Inside each `LinearLayout` slot I have a horizonal `LinearLayout` that holds 2 things a word and a number. The problem is some of the words are hidden?? and it takes up half the screen. Thanks for any help.

[Layout bounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOJXr.png)

[image: Problem]

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
    LinearLayout horizontal = new LinearLayout(context);
    horizontal.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams LLParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    horizontal.setLayoutParams(LLParams);

    btnWord.add(i, new Button(context));
    btnWord.get(i).setHeight(60);
    btnWord.get(i).setWidth(120);
    btnWord.get(i).setTypeface(montFont);
    btnWord.get(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    btnWord.get(i).setTag(i);
    btnWord.get(i).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    btnWord.get(i).setText("  " + words.get(i));
    btnWord.get(i).setOnClickListener(btnClicked);
    horizontal.addView(btnWord.get(i));

    wordWeight.add(i, new Button(context));
    wordWeight.get(i).setHeight(60);
    wordWeight.get(i).setWidth(40);
    wordWeight.get(i).setTypeface(montFont);
    wordWeight.get(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    wordWeight.get(i).setTag(i);
    wordWeight.get(i).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    wordWeight.get(i).setText("  " + wordWeights.get(i));
    wordWeight.get(i).setOnClickListener(btnClicked);
    horizontal.addView(wordWeight.get(i));

    linearLayout.addView(horizontal);
}
```

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ScrollView"
        android:layout_marginTop="106dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout" />

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Go to your developer options and activate your "show layout bounds", take another screenshot and post it here.

Comment: layout bounds added @Mauker

Comment: Why don't you use a `ListView` with a custom adapter or a `RecyclerView` instead of programmatically add Views?

Comment: Ill have a look into it @Mauker

Comment: @Mauker I think you meant a `ListView` in your first comment. Alex, I think you should look into a ListView or Recyclerview for this behavior, it will work a lot smoother for you.

Comment: Ooops. What are you talking about? :) Jk, thanks for noticing, I've edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to set the `weight` of each "item" to 1 so they will equally divide the space on the screen. Something like the snippet below:

```
LinearLayout ll;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp;
lp.weight = 1;
ll.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

You could also ditch that logic and use a `ListView` with a custom adapter like I did on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462112/listview-updated-from-edittext/30462677#30462677), or setup a `RecyclerView` as you can see on [this blog post](http://androidessence.com/how-to-use-the-recyclerview-adapter/). It's way easier and more efficient to do either one of those.

More on `ListView` vs. `RecyclerView` [here](http://androidessence.com/recyclerview-vs-listview/).

Comment: This is the "correct" answer to the incorrect solution the OP is using. :) Using Weights and creating this list programmatically is less efficient and harder to maintain than dropping a simple ListView or RecyclerView. But +1 for fixing the problem :)