# How to create custom adapter for custom listview with Hashmap

Tags: android, listview

How i can create a custom adapter for this xml.Can someone guide me on how to create a custom adapter or give me a sample code on how to do it. Please help me i need to learn how to create custom adapter.Help me please. Thanks in advance.

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.work.listviewadapter;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final String PRODUCTLIST_URL ="http://192.168.56.1/productlist.php";


private ProgressDialog pDialog;

public  static  final JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

private static final String GET_PRODUCT = "message";

private static final String GET_ID = "ID";

private static final String GET_BRAND = "Brand";

private static final String GET_CATEGORY = "Category";

private static final String GET_DESCRIPTION = "Description";

private static final String GET_CODE = "Code";

private static final String GET_QUANTITY = "Quantity";

private static final String GET_UNIT = "Unit";

private static final String GET_UNITPRICE = "Unitprice";

private JSONArray order = null;

ListView list;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> orderlist;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.productlist);

new LoadComments().execute();


}


public void updateJSONdata() {

    orderlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(PRODUCTLIST_URL);


    try {


        order = json.getJSONArray(GET_PRODUCT);

        for (int i = 0; i < order.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject c = order.getJSONObject(i);

            String id = c.getString(GET_ID);

            String brand = c.getString(GET_BRAND);

            String category = c.getString(GET_CATEGORY);

            String description = c.getString(GET_DESCRIPTION);

            String code = c.getString(GET_CODE);

            String quantity = c.getString(GET_QUANTITY);

            String unit = c.getString(GET_UNIT);

            String unitprice = c.getString(GET_UNITPRICE);



            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(GET_ID,id);

            map.put(GET_BRAND, brand);

            map.put(GET_CATEGORY, category);

            map.put(GET_DESCRIPTION, description);

            map.put(GET_CODE, code);

            map.put(GET_QUANTITY, quantity);

            map.put(GET_UNIT, unit);

            map.put(GET_UNITPRICE, unitprice);


            orderlist.add(map);

            }

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

private void updateList() {

    //this is for my custom listview

}

final  public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Order...");

        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);

        pDialog.setCancelable(true);

        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        //we will develop this method in version 2

        updateJSONdata();

        return null;

    }

    @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        pDialog.dismiss();

        //we will develop this method in version 2

        updateList();

    }

}

}
```

This is my Custom ListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Quantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="10000"
    android:textSize="24dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="51dp"
    >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Unit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Gal."
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="White"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Code"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Wpu-01"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Description"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Brand"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Code"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:text="Weber"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Urethane"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Code"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Brand"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/Category" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Category"
    android:text="P"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:id="@+id/P"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="10000.00"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Brand"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/P"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="11"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This for the listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:singleLine="true"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_below="@+id/search"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:divider="#ff5873ff"
    android:dividerHeight="3dp" />
```

Comment: ........so ? `what is the issue ?`

Comment: I learning how to use custom adapter for my listview but i don't know how to implement custom adapter with Hashmap in it. Can you help me build my own adapter base on my code above?.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26840700/1761003

Comment: ok thanks for the help

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can design your `BaseAdapter` like below code, also you can optimize listview performance using `ViewHolder` pattern

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater mlayoutInflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        mlayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);  //Dynamic layout mapping
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return orderlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = mlayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);  //  According to the layout of the document to instantiate view
        TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText(orderlist.get(position).get(GET_BRAND).toString());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: in your Activity class

Comment: A link alone as an answer is a bad answer in my book.  Links break and the answer becomes worthless later even if the linked material answered the question initially.  At least if you include a summary, the answer can somewhat stand on its own.

See the fledgling FAQ on [how to write a good answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

I'll use a custom adapter I've made as an example. It may solve your problem if you follow the steps and shape it to your needs.

[image: Final result]

When you want to make a custom `ListView`, you have to write your own adapter. In this particular case I'm subclassing the [`BaseAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) class.

This custom adapter will take hold of my data model, and will inflate the data to my `ListView` rows.

First, I'll create the XML of my custom row. You can see the code below.

**item_mail.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test text"
        android:id="@+id/tv_mail"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_report_image" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here I've created a row that displays a text and an image.

Now, I'll create my custom adapter to handle this XML. As you can see below.

**MailAdapter.java**

```
public class MailAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = MailAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context context_;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mailitems;

    public MailAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mailitems) {
        this.context_ = context;
        this.mailitems = mailitems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mailitems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mailitems.get(position).get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context_.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_mail, null);
        }

        TextView tv_mail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_mail);
        ImageView iv_icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon);

        String mail = mailitems.get(position).get(0);
        String icon = mailitems.get(position).get(1);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Mail: " + mail + " mail_icon: " + icon);

        tv_mail.setText(mail);
        // iv_icon.setImageURI(); Here you can do whatever logic you want to update your image, using URI's, ID's, or something else.

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Ok. Now we have everything to make this work. In your `Activity` class, do something like that:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:id="@+id/tv_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_header">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add mail"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private int numMail = 1; // Dummy int to create my items with different numbers.

    private MailAdapter mailAdapter; // Your custom adapter.

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mailItems; // This is going to be your data structure, everytime you change it, call the notifyDataSetChanged() method.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        ListView lv_mail = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mailItems = new ArrayList<>();
        mailAdapter = new MailAdapter(this,mailItems);
        lv_mail.setAdapter(mailAdapter);

        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addItem(); // The method I'm using to insert the item. Look for it below.
            }
        });
    }

    // Here I'm creating a new ArrayList, and appending it to my 'mailItems' Array. After that, I'm notifying the adapter that my data changed.
    private void addItem() {
        ArrayList<String> mail = new ArrayList<>();

        mail.add(0,"mail " + numMail++);
        mail.add(1,"path_to_image"); // Depending on what you want to do, put your path, URI, or whatever other way you want to store that image data.

        mailItems.add(mail); // Inserting the data on the ArrayList.
        mailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notifying the adapter that my ArrayList was modified.
    }
}
```

This should do the trick.

You can read a little more about that [here](http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.com.br/) and I've found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540754/dynamically-add-elements-to-a-listview-android), which you can read as well.

Edit: Another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799380/understanding-baseadapters-and-how-to-use-them), which might be an interesting read.